# how to get 1 recent comments of a post on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so on my index blade im trying to show one lastest for the post and it seems im getting error please any help i will really appreciate
the error im getting

Error
Call to a member function last() on string (View:

```
 @foreach ( $post->comments as $comment )
      {{ $comment->body->last() }}
   @endforeach
```

Comment: what type of data contains `$post->comments;` ?

Comment: all comment body , created at user id and post id

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$post->comments->latest()->first();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
@foreach ($post->comments->latest()->first() as $comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already defined the relationship in post model like this:

```
public function comments()
   {
    return hasMany(Post::class)
   }
```

```
Just retrive data like this:
```

```
$post = Post::with('comments')->latest()->first();
```

Now in view file just use:

```
$post->comments;
```